# Azure VM storage disks - can I choose which ever Premium storage disk size, or am I limited to the P10, P20 and P30?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

Regarding Azure Premium disk sizes, I'm somewhat confused. Documentation, e.g. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-premium-storage), clearly states, that premium disks come in 3 sizes: P10 (128GB), P20 (512GB) and P30 (1024GB). These are fixed sizes.

But if I go to the portal, find my VM, click *"Disks"* and *"Add data disk"* I get to choose between Premium (SSD) and Standard (HDD) - and in either case, I can specify exact size. I.e. choosing SSD does not limit me to the 3 aforementioned options. Am I missing something?

Also, bonus question: is the Premium storage billed per-GB-used or for entire disk size allocated? (I've seen both billing methods mentioned in Microsoft docs!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premium disks are only available in those three sizes. If you choose something smaller than, say, 128GB (P10), you still get a P10 disk, but you just can't use all of it. Same with, say, asking for 800GB - you'll get a P30.

Premium storage is committed SSD, and you pay for the full commitment (unlike creating a page blob vhd in regular storage, where it's sparse-allocated).

Note: With Managed Disks, you pay for full allocation for both regular and premium disks, though the cost for regular (non-SSD) storage is less than premium (SSD) storage.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David. Just the clarification I needed. So basically it's a portal UI-issue, I guess. Looks like this question is getting closed off soon, but I'm grateful I saw your answer before that :)